# magento 1.9.2.1 image upload gets never completed

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I read several posts but none of them has been useful. When I try to upload an product image, the uploader starts and goes up to 100% but then it turnes red, the image is not uploaded. If I try to upload the image not from product but from page, the upload seems to go fine but then the image is not shown in the folder and if I check the folder with filezilla I can see that the image is not there (so it's not been uploaded). Both ways, no error is shown, system and exception logs shows nothing. Magento version is 1.9.2.1, php is version 5.6 and gd is enabled. Permsision and user/group are correct.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you check you system.log enable from admin? Also check console when you try to upload the image.

Comment: I found the issue: it's a plugin (page builder from venus) that's causing the issue. If I disable the plugin, the uploader works fine

Answer (score 0):

When You upload the image from admin panel there can be an issue of Adobe plugin that is installed on your browser mainly in Filezilla.

When you upload the image from the page be sure it is placed in the correct path as the product images come from the media/cache folder.

Try like this:

```
$filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
    $ourProduct->save();
    echo "done ";
}
```

Try to clear cache and run Flush Catalog Images Cache in Admin